# Can't use GDAL with Python for opening *.GML file (vector file) from Sentinel-2 (L2A type) imagery *.zip archive

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, gdalwarp, sentinel-2, gdalinfo

I'm trying to use GDAL 3.0.4 to open some of the *.gml files directly from the Sentinel-2 *.zip archive with following lines:

```
gml_path = f'GML:/vsizip//s2zip_path/path_to_GML_file'
gml_ds = gdal.Open(gml_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
```

but I receive an exception like:
"Exception: GML:vsizip//zip path//path to file: No such file or directory

I doubled checked several times the used path and it is fine. I also made a try without mentioning the driver, like this:

```
gml_path = f'/vsizip//s2zip_path/path_to_GML_file'
gml_ds = gdal.Open(gml_path, gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
```

and it seems now that GDAL saw the file but it through another exception like 'not recognized as a supported file format.'

I would like to do fix that for a script.

What can be wrong ?

Comment: Hi George, welcome to gis-se! GDAL is the name of the whole project, but there do exists three Modules for raster (gdal), vector(ogr) and projections (osr) and even more smaller ones (https://gdal.org/python/index.html). So, try to use ogr with your gml file!

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for answering  @AndreasMüller !

I'm using now something like this:
`from gdal import ogr
gml_ds = ogr.Open(vector_path)
print(gml_ds )`

After some tests I concluded that _vector_path_ is too long. Can you give me a tip if there is a way to make shorter file_path without changing the folder structure or to bypass the issue?

Comment: I'm using a very long '/vsizip/....' _vector_path_. I'm trying to get to some of the *.gml files from the QI_DATA folder. The path until this locations is too long even in the sentinel-2 zip file.

Comment: I suggest to open another question, explicitly asking for path length in gdal. I can't answer your question. Also try to  give a reproducable exsmple.

Comment: This is the Python code that I'm using:

`from osgeo import ogr
driver_cloud = ogr.GetDriverByName('GML')
cloud_ds = driver_cloud.Open('/vsizip/./s2_data_test/S2A_MSIL2A_20200406T093031_N0214_R136_T34TFS_20200406T115344.zip/S2A_MSIL2A_20200406T093031_N0214_R136_T34TFS_20200406T115344.SAFE/GRANULE/L2A_T34TFS_A025015_20200406T093031/QI_DATA/MSK_CLOUDS_B00.gml')
print(cloud_ds)`
<br/>
The last print returns nothing because the system seems to overload and it does not access the file.

Comment: If I'm manually unzip the desired GML file and inserting in another ZIP test archive with similar folder substructure, with subfolder names with any length (more than 210 chars), the script is working.<br/>
What can it be ? Is there a way to fix this?<br/>
I'm coding inside Ubuntu 18 WSL under Windows 10 Pro.
<br/>